# Alternative to declaring a type alias inside a class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

I am using a class (`sf::Texture`) from another library.
I want to get the functionality of declaring a type alias inside that class, like:

```
class Texture
{
public:
    using ResourceId = TextureId;
    //...
}
```

so that I can do this in my code:

```
enum class TextureId
{
    texture1,
    texture2 //..etc
}

template<class ResourceType>
class ResourceContainer
{
public:
    ResourceContainer();
private:
    ResourceType* resource_;
    typename ResourceType::ResourceId id; // <--- this will have TextureId type
                                          // when we create this object 
                                          // with <sf::Texture>
}
```

However, as I mentioned, the `Texture` class is from another library so I can't edit its declaration.

I tried to declare it in my code as `using sf::Texture::ResourceId = TextureId;` but it doesn't work(Cannot resolve the symbol *ResourceId*).

So, is there an alternative to get the same functionality without adding `ResourceId` as the second template parameter?

(using C++17)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use a trait class to derive the `ResourceId` and specialise it for `Texture`. e.g:

```
template < typename T >
struct ResourceTypeTrait
{
  using ResourceId = typename T::ResourceId;
};

template <>
struct ResourceTypeTrait< Texture >
{
  using ResourceId = TextureId;
};
```

Then you can do:

```
template<class ResourceType>
class ResourceContainer
{
public:
    ResourceContainer();
private:
    ResourceType* resource_;
    typename ResourceTypeTrait< ResourceType >::ResourceId id;
};
```